# Comparing across 2 database instances

Tags: oracle, release-management

I have a problem with 2 databases that I have created on my local machine. I keep changing one of the database instances(say SID A) and the other instance(say SID B) is only changed once every 2-3 weeks. I want to find out all the changes that I have done on the local DB (Procedures, inserts, deletions, functions etc.) in SID A. Both the instances have 10 users, and the changes are present across all the 10 users.

I have tried to do a "diff" in sqldeveloper, but I end up getting a list of all the tables, procedures etc. - all to be created in SID B.

I have seen some tools, ready made scripts etc.

Is there a definite way that I am missing - I dont want to do a database export and import every time I want to migrate the changes.

Database: Oracle 10G

Thanks in advance for helping out.

Thanks,
Contrib

Comment: Do you want to find the changes, or to put DB "B" just as DB "A" is?

Comment: @Plouf! I want to find out the changes that have happened in DB "A", with scripts for changed objects (create, delete, modify) and one more for Data (Inserts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use a tool like [Red Gate's "Schema Compare for Oracle"](http://www.red-gate.com/products/oracle-development/schema-compare-for-oracle/); it's rock solid and will do exactly what you need it to, pretty much out of the box.

Before going down this sort of route though, I would suggest that you think about how you are deploying changes to your environments. For example, if you stored the incremental DML and DDL changes you made to schema A in source control, you could then play those in against schema B very easily.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I did explore Red Gate along with Toad compare and Sqldeveloper diff. However, I am thinking along the lines of a service which runs every day and finds out changes that have happened in SID A as against the CVS. If conflicts are listed out in a csv file, that would allow manual resolution, whereas all others are automatically checked into CVS. What am I thinking wrong here? (Or overlooking any complexity?)

Comment: That's what I'm getting at, rather than having a service that's doing diffs, if you apply all of your changes from incremental updates (patches) stored in source control, you don't need diffs, you should be able to just apply the same changes to another environment and you're done. You can store a list of applied patches in the database if it makes that easier to see where to start from.

Comment: or are you talking user data replication?

Comment: it is a mixture of user data and schemas. but i am much more clear on the subject now. running direct incremental updates as patches does make sense. thanks!